# call to a member function non-object

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm beginning with PHP and i need your help.

I create a try to list all members who has the same interest that the current_member( i mean the connected member ).

I write this :

```
$current_members = params('current_member');
    $members_all = option('db')->query('SELECT * FROM members WHERE interest = $current_members["interest"] ORDER BY lastname, firstname')->fetchAll();

    set('members_all', $members_all);
```

When I go on my page I have the error :
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object

And in my view I just write this :

```
        <h2 id="member-<?= $member['id'] ?>">

            <?= avatar_tag($member,'30x30') ?>

            <a href="<?=member_url_for($member)?>"><?=$member['firstname']?><small> <?= $member['lastname'] ?></small></a>

        </h2>
```

I dont understand this error, anyone can help me ?

Thank's for your help.

Comment: The call to `query` probably failed. You can see that by storing the result of the call in a variable.

Comment: Your SQL query did not complete successfully.  Do *not* ever just *assume* your query succeeded.  You need to check for errors *before* calling `fetchAll()`.  Chaining `query()->fetchAll()` is bad practice.  Do something like `$query = query(); if($query){ $query->fetchAll(); } else{ die(mysqli_error($query); }` (or whatever, that's just pseudo-code).

Comment: hum , ok how i can do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not chain calls to `query()` and `fetchAll()` like you are doing.  That's bad practice.  Never assume your query worked, always check to see if it did.

```
$db = option('db');
$query = $db->query('SELECT ...');
if($query === FALSE){
    print_r($db->errorInfo());
    die;
}
$members_all = $query->fetchAll();
```

<sub>(Since you are calling `fetchAll()`, I assume you are using PDO (and not MySQLi))</sub>

Also, do *not* try to concatenate variables into your SQL query.  (P.S. You're not even doing that, you are using single quotes, so `$current_members["interest"]` is not being read as a variable) That's just asking for an SQL injection attack.  What you want to do is use prepared statements.

```
$db = option('db');
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM members WHERE interest = ? ORDER BY lastname, firstname');
$exec = $query->execute(array($current_members['interest']));
if($exec === FALSE){
    print_r($query->errorInfo());
    die;
}
$members_all = $query->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

IN your sql query

```
'SELECT * FROM members WHERE interest = $current_members["interest"] ORDER BY lastname, firstname'
```

you are using single quotes, so $current_members["interest"] actually does not resolve to a PHP variable, it is a string. You can switch single and double quotes:

Made an edit here, passing array offset was not fortunate:

```
$interest = $current_members['interest'];
"SELECT * FROM members WHERE interest = $interest ORDER BY lastname, firstname"
```

Unfortunately you did not share any of the underlying database code, but assuming option('db') is a pdo object, this should work fine.

If option('db') really is a pdo, before executing any statement add:

```
option('db') -> setAttribute( \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

this will tell you the exact error

Comment: if i try this :

$members_all = option('db')->query('SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY lastname, firstname')->fetchAll();

I can list all members. But if i add WHERE, that fail.

Answer (score 0):

The "call to a member function on a non-object" error, means that you are trying to call a method on a variable that does not represent an object.

You have the following methods called one after the other on the $members_all denifition:
option('db')->query("...")->fetchAll();

You call the method "query" of whatever returns option('db') with some SQL query, and then you call fetchAll() method to whatever returns that "query" method.

I do not know if I explained myself well, the main point is that when you execute the *query* method it is returning something that has not the "fetchAll" method, in your case your SQL is wrong and probably query() is returning NULL or FALSE instead of a result set.

Change your single quotes with double quotes or concatenate the $current_member['interest'] variable.