# PHP MySQLi Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Getting this error and not sure what's going on. New to using mysqli.

```
$query = 'SELECT name, email FROM US__users WHERE state="' . $state . '" ORDER BY zip ASC LIMIT 5';
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
  print ($row['name'] . ' ' . $row['email']);
}

$result->free();
```

There's currently only one row in MySQL DB. However, when I copy the $query and run it at the mysql command prompt, it queries fine and displays one result.

Comment: You should use a prepared statement with placeholders and bind your variable to this placeholder. That would take care of your error and your sql injection vulnerability too.

Comment: The variable comes from another php file and not something that a user can set. Each file has $state = ''; and depending which file they use, populates the $state variable in this query. So I don't believe that would be cause for SQL injection.

Comment: That's no cause not to use prepared statements. There are other issues too. Where is your error checking?

Answer (score 2):

The query string is syntactically incorrect. You have this:

```
$query = 'SELECT name, email FROM users WHERE state="' $state '" ORDER BY zip ASC LIMIT 5';
```

Try this instead using double quotes (`"`) which allow for string substitution:

```
$query = "SELECT name, email FROM users WHERE state='$state' ORDER BY zip ASC LIMIT 5";
```

Or this if you want concatenation of values in the string for some reason:

```
$query = "SELECT name, email FROM users WHERE state='" . $state . "' ORDER BY zip ASC LIMIT 5";
```

Another idea if you still have issues is to use a prepared statement method; you never know if `state` needs to be filtered or not. So try this.

```
$query = "SELECT name, email FROM US__users WHERE state=? ORDER BY zip ASC LIMIT 5";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

$stmt->bind_param('s', $state);

$result = $stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();

while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
  print ($row['name'] . ' ' . $row['email']);
}

$result->free();
```

Comment: The query isn't syntactically incorrect, but the concatenation which builds the query is.

Comment: which makes it syntactically incorrect as a result

Comment: @JakeGould Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in

Comment: yes, and if I change the password or some value it'll give me a connection error message.

Comment: @JakeGould the error is now failing at while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

Answer (score 0):

You are missing concatenation on your query definition:

```
$query = 'SELECT name, email FROM users WHERE state="' . $state . '" ORDER BY zip ASC LIMIT 5';
```

Take a look at following link for further info:
[call to a member function non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315517/call-to-a-member-function-non-object/24315621#24315621)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that PHP shouldn't have got this far - it should terminate at the syntax error where concat operators are omitted.

Comment: I forgot to put the concatenation. I edited my first post.

Comment: Totally but the author seems to not have this problem. Any idea?

Comment: @user3727412 if the concatenation is not the problem, then you probably have some kind of error in your SQL query.

The main error you are reporting is because the *query* call is not generating what you expect to be.

Comment: but the query works in mysql and phpmyadmin. So why would it not work here?

Comment: That's pretty weird ... Are you connecting successfully to your database? Try a simple query like a `describe US__users`.
I saw in other comments that you tested the connection is ok. What data type is the state field ?

Comment: No error doing a describe.

Comment: Fields are either vchar or int.

Answer (score -1):

Query is breaking due to

```
state="' $state '"
```

Try as

```
$query = "SELECT name, email FROM 
users WHERE state='$state' ORDER BY zip ASC LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: Still having error. Is it because the table name has a double underscore?

Comment: no double underscore should not be an issue. And down voter it would be nice if you leave a reason too.

Comment: ok, then not sure why i'm still getting an error.

Comment: are you sure you are connected to mysql ? check if its connected to mysql before executing the query.

Comment: It is, I changed $host to $hst and I saw the connection error.

Comment: if the connection is fine and there is a value for `$state` then it should work, what you get if you do a simple query like `SELECT name, email FROM users order by zip LIMIT 5` ?

Comment: So the initial issue was I renamed the table and the user didn't have permissions. But now I'm getting an error regarding @JakeGould on his while loop.

Answer (score -1):

It could be a PHP bug? Just faced the same issue. So it doesn't work as you wanted (for future people, who like me will be searching for the answer): `while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {`. But for some reason it works like this(looks pretty ugly though)

```
$query = 'SELECT name, email FROM US__users WHERE state="' . $state . '" ORDER BY zip ASC LIMIT 5';

while ($row = $mysqli->fetch_array($query)) {...
```